# Reverse the Key and value of a Pair in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to reverse the Key and value Pair of Customer ID and Number of Visits:

```
scala> val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
(48784,3)
(47847,10)
(87673,8)
(67654,4)
```

I would like to reverse this pair to look something like this:

```
(3,48784)
(10,47847)
(8,87673)
(4,67654)
```

I've research similar answers to this question on this site and have tried the following.

1. `input.map{ pair => pair.swap}`
2. `val PairReverse = pair.map(X => (x._2,x._1))`
3. `val PairReverse = pair.map(X => ((1),(0))`

I keep getting the following error:

> "Map value is not a member of this Unit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove `.foreach(println)` from the following line and you should be fine

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)
```

as `foreach` is an *action* and returns `unit()` . `foreach` definition looks as

> > def foreach(f: T => Unit): Unit

After the removal of `foreach()`, **the followings should work** for you

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val pairReverse = input.map(pair => pair.swap)
pairReverse.foreach(println)
```

**Or**

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val pairReverse = pair.map(x => (x._2,x._1))
pairReverse.foreach(println)
```

**But** *the last map that you tried* **will not work** i.e.

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val pairReverse = pair.map(X => ((1),(0)))
pairReverse.foreach(println)
```

**as it will produce (1,0) tuples for each pairs you have** as

```
(1,0)
(1,0)
(1,0)
(1,0)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

`pair` is of type `Unit` because of using `foreach`, as it's not a functional operation (its result is a `Unit`). If you add `.map(X => (x._2,x._1))` just before `foreach` invocation, like this:

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).
    reduceByKey(_+_).map(X => (x._2,x._1)).foreach(println)
```

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)
```

This returns `Unit`, the `foreach(println)` makes the pair to be unit.

```
val pair = input.map(line => line.split(" ") (2)).map(input => (input, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
// now print the pair rdd
pair.foreach(println)

//Now you can use it to swap using one of the following
pair.map(_.swap)
pair.map(x => (x._2,x._1))
pair.map(X => ((1),(0)))
```

So just remove the `foreach(println)` and should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to swap key, value pair of each element using `collect`

```
 val map = Map(48784->3, 47847 -> 10, 87673 -> 8, 67654 -> 4)
 map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(48784 -> 3, 47847 -> 10, 87673 -> 8, 67654 -> 4)

scala> map.collect{
    case e => e._2 -> e._1
}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(3 -> 48784, 10 -> 47847, 8 -> 87673, 4 -> 67654)
```